# How can I get PyPDF2 metadata from a Minio bucket object?

Tags: python, pypdf, minio

I can do two things separately but cannot combine them. I want to get PyPDF2 metadata on a few hundred objects in a Minio bucket.

If I have a PDF stored locally, I can do this:

```
input = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(filename, "rb")
print(input.getDocumentInfo())
```

Likewise, I can print all objects in a Minio bucket like this:

```
objects = client.list_objects(bucket)
for obj in objects:
    print(obj.object_name)
```

But it doesn't work when I put the PyPDF2 statements in the for loop.

```
objects = client.list_objects(bucket)

for obj in objects:
    doc = client.fget_object(bucket,object_name=obj.object_name, file_path=obj.object_name)    
    input = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(doc, "rb")
```

PyPDF2 gives an error

```
AttributeError: 'Object' object has no attribute 'seek'
```

How can I get this to work? Thanks very much.

Comment: You need `io.BytesIO`